# How do I check if sqlite database was created successfully?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-file

I'm having trouble figuring out if I created my database correctly.

I'm trying to locate a .db file to check if database was created successfully but can't find it anywhere in my project explorer, what is correct way to check for database, and it would help to know where such file is located (in project not device) in order to view its data.

Comment: It should be in **/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db**

Comment: @Vyger I fail to locate data folder, starting from the very top I have build, src and libs folders, wich one should lead to data, I'm browsing through them at the moment

Comment: Maybe you forgot to select the device in the left pane...

Comment: If the db doesn't create... I'd change the name of the fields `date` and `time`, because they could be reserved words. At least `date`.

Comment: OH! I gave for free that you were in the **DDMS** perspective. No, you are still in Java - So, switch to the **DDMS** perspective, select the device and then follow the path.

Comment: @Vyger hard, but I found the directory :D at the moment I can only see cache and lib folders in com.example.myappname.app folder (I think thats right one inside data/data) there is no databases folder, does that mean that it was not created?

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid you have to change those field names... try with `date` first. If still doesn't create the db, change `time` too. You don't have to change them much: `db_date` and `db_time` will be enough different names.

Comment: @Vyger cool, will try, meanwhile I assume that even thought DatabaseHandler is not main activity it still runs it code on app launch right, as it is in a onCreate() method, or do I need to call it from somewhere?

Comment: the onCreate is only called when u make an instance of the helper class.

Comment: It launches on the class creation, done by the main activity (when you declare "new DataBaseHandler...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my comment here:

If you're trying to view the db on an actual device, the internal data directory is typically protected. On an emulated device you can (also some rooted phones).

I understand "project explorer" to be the explorer for the source code?  You're db does not exist there, the dir/file exist only on the device...this is the code to create the db. As others now have explained, to view the device files in Eclipse, you need to use the DDMS panel.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you little.

In eclipse>Open perspective>DDMS

in this location you will be able to find all the database files which are related to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database, sending the

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

query should return a list with all the tables in your database. If instead you get an error or no results, you know something is up.